# WPF: Using the value from listbox which binding with a datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am new here and this is my first question.

I am designing a textblock that can enquire my database when I change the text. After that, user can choose a value in the listbox, and then the textblock should change its value to what has been selected.

I was successful to retrieve the value I chose in the listbox when I using Messagebox.Show, but when I changed the value in the textblock again, or I want to change the textblock value, VS show an error message with System.NullReferenceException.

I would like to learn the root cause so that I can avoid it in the future. And I also want to know is it possible to retieve more than one record from the listbox. Thanks a lot!

Below is my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Searchbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="85,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" TextChanged="Read_DB"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="321,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="result_box" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="85,61,216,155" SelectionChanged="result_box_SelectionChanged" />

</Grid>
```

Below is the code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Read_DB(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLite_Class SQLite = new SQLite_Class();
        string sql_command = "Select  * from mytable where name like '%" +Searchbox.Text + "%' limit 10";
        DataTable listdata = SQLite.data_query(sql_command, "mydb.db");

        result_box.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        result_box.ItemsSource = listdata.DefaultView;
        result_box.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
        result_box.SelectedValuePath = "ID";            
    }

    private void result_box_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
        DataRowView view = lb.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        string test = view["ID"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(test);
        Searchbox.Text = test;
        //result_box.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for that. Only need to change the show action when the datarowview is not null can perfectly solve that.

```
private void result_box_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataRowView view = result_box.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            if (view != null)
            {                    
                MessageBox.Show(view["ID"].ToString());
                Searchbox.Text = view["ID"].ToString();
            } 

    }
```